# MSBuild: Copy dependency files before the NUnit task run

Tags: msbuild, nunit, testrunconfig, integration-testing

We are migrating from `MSTests` to `NUnit`. The first step was to migrate all our UnitTests projects which was accomplished using the following msbuild task:

```
<Target Name="RunTests">

    <!-- The location of the necessary tools to run nunit tests -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NUnitToolPath>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0</NUnitToolPath>
        <NUnitResultTool>C:\Program Files\NUnit For Team Build Version 1.2</NUnitResultTool>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Create a build step representing running nunit tests -->
    <BuildStep TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)" BuildUri="$(BuildUri)" Name="NUnitTestStep" Message="Running Nunit Tests">
        <Output TaskParameter="Id" PropertyName="NUnitStepId" />
    </BuildStep>

    <!-- Specify which dll's to include when running tests -->
    <CreateItem Include="$(OutDir)\Profdoc.UnitTests*.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TestAssembly" />
    </CreateItem>

    <NUnit
        Assemblies="@(TestAssembly)"
        ToolPath="$(NUnitToolPath)"
        OutputXmlFile="$(OutDir)\NUnit_TestResults.xml"
        ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="NUnitResult" />
    </NUnit>

    <!-- Update the build step result based on the output from the NUnit task -->
    <BuildStep Condition="'$(NUnitResult)'=='0'" TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)" BuildUri="$(BuildUri)" Id="$(NUnitStepId)" Status="Succeeded" />
    <BuildStep Condition="'$(NUnitResult)'!='0'" TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)" BuildUri="$(BuildUri)" Id="$(NUnitStepId)" Status="Failed" />

    <!-- Upload the results to TFS. -->
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(NUnitResultTool)\NUnitTFS.exe&quot; -n &quot;$(OutDir)\NUnit_TestResults.xml&quot; -t &quot;$(TeamProject)&quot; -b &quot;$(BuildNumber)&quot; -f &quot;%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)&quot; -p &quot;%(ConfigurationToBuild.PlatformToBuild)&quot; -x &quot;$(NUnitResultTool)\NUnitToMSTest.xslt&quot;" />

    <!-- Indicate build failure if any tests failed -->
    <Error Condition="'$(NUnitResult)'!='0'" Text="Unit Tests Failed" />
</Target>
```

But i'm at a loss as to how we are going to accomplish the same with out integration tests, because we need to deploy settings and licence files to the binary folder before running the tests. So, how can i deploy files to the binary folder, preferably as a part of the NUnit task (because i want to run the IntegrationTests against different configuration setups)?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to create new one target which will copy all required files and make target `RunTests` dependent on new one, basically:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LicenseFiles>$(PathToLicenseFiles)\**\*.lcx</LicenseFiles>
    <SettingsFiles>$(PathToConfigFiles)\**\*.config</SettingsFiles>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <Files Include="$(LicenseFiles);$(SettingsFiles)"
          Exclude="*.tmp"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyDependencyFiles">
  <CopyFiles Inputs="@(Files)" Outputs="..." />
</Target>

<!-- Run Integration tests after all files were copied -->
<Target Name="RunIntegrationTests" DependsOnTargets="CopyDependencyFiles">
  <NUnit .. />
</Target>
```